# In topological space $X$, if $C\subset A\cup B\subset X$ is such that $C\cap A$ and $C\cap B$ are opne in $A$ and $B$, then is $C$ open in $A\cup B$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be subsets of a topological space $X$ with $C \subset A \cup B$.

If $C$ is open in $A \cup B$ (with the relative topology), then $C = (A \cup B) \cap U$ for some open set $U$ of $X$. So we have
$$
C \cap A = \big[ (A \cup B) \cap U \big] \cap A = \big[ (A \cup B) \cap A \big] \cap U   = A \cap U,
$$
which is open in $A$, and we also have
$$
C \cap B = \big[ (A \cup B) \cap U \big] \cap B = \big[ (A \cup B) \cap B \big] \cap U   = B \cap U,
$$
which is open in $B$.

Thus if $C$ is open in $A \cup B$, then $C \cap A$ is open in $A$ and $C \cap B$ is opne in $B$.

Now let us suppose that $C \cap A$ is open in $A$ and $C \cap B$ is opne in $B$. Then there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $C \cap A = U \cap A$ and $C \cap B = V \cap B$, which implies that
\begin{align}
C &= C \cap (A \cup B) \\
&= (C \cap A) \cup (C \cap B) \\
&= (U \cap A) \cup (V \cap B). 
\end{align}
Can we complete this argument to show that $C$ is open in $A \cup B$?

Answer (score 2):

> Can we complete this argument to show that $C$ is open in $A \cup B$?

No, because that's not true. Take any topological space with non-open subset $A$, its complement $B=X\backslash A$ and $C=A$. So such example exists in every non-discrete space.

Answer (score 0):

The if and only if statement $C$ is open in $A\cup B\iff C\cap A$ and $C\cap B$ are open is only true if the cover of $A\cup B$ by $\{A,B\}$ is a [fundamental cover](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306789/are-all-covers-fundamental) .

There are several ways in which this cover(by two elements) can be fundamental. For example if $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously closed sets( closed in $A\cup B$) or if $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously open sets(open in $A\cup B$) . But it might fail otherwise. Now in what ways a cover can be fundamental depends on the space $X$.  In general a cover by open sets(open cover) and a finite closed cover is always fundamental.

The example by freakish shows a counter example. Notice that $A$ is not open in $A\cup B = X$ in his example whereas $B$ is closed.